# Trying to compile program that uses zlib. Link unresolved error

Tags: c++, compilation, zlib

While trying to compile program, that uses zlib, i got following errors:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol _compress referenced
>   in function "void __cdecl
>   save_image_in_pakfile(class
>   std::basic_ofstream > &,struct
>   _IplImage *)" (?save_image_in_pakfile@@YAXAAV?$basic_ofstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@PAU_IplImage@@@Z)  buffer_management.obj
>
> Error 2   error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   _compress fern_based_point_classifier.obj

And two more same errors but related to uncompress function.

I use the vs2008 C++, and at the project properties I added in 
C/C++ : Additional include directories the path to header files of zlib. 
And at linker properties I added at additional dependencies:
zlibwapi.lib and zlibstat.lib files.

How to resolv the problem?
If I made some mistakes please show me them..

Comment: Is zlib code compiled as C code or as C++ code?

Comment: zlib code goes with vs2008 project. So I just opened and compiled it.

Comment: You really should look at the compiler settings for the zlib source files.

Comment: So you think there must not be any mistakes in the project that uses zlib, but only in zlib project?

Comment: I've downloaded another sources with VS2008 project files of zlib and choose "LIB debug" configuration.
So the project that uses zlib compiled successfuly! You were right, I should have changed the zlib's compiler settings. But I still do not know what setting have to be changed at the old zlib project, I should compare to projects's settings in order to understand it.